# Check to see if a string contains elements of delimited string from QueryString

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/NewDataSet/Row[contains(translate(string(@ImpactedBusiness),'&amp;amp;','&amp;'),$ParamBusiness)]"/>
```

This code will find and return rows where the querystring is included in the ImpactedBusiness string

So, ImpactedBusiness could be something like **DS;GF;P&T;SITI;UA;UI**

If the URL is **www.blahblah.com/Dashboard.aspx?Business=DS**, a row with the above ImpactedBusiness will be returned.

But if the URL is **www.blahblah.com/Dashboard.aspx?Business=TR** then that row will not be returned.

Is it possible to make it so that I can type URL like **wwww.blahblah.com/Dashboard.aspx?Business=DS,TR,GF** and have any row which contains either of those comma delimited elements is returned

Comment: You really need to show more of your stylesheet (for instance, the definition of the parameter `ParamBusiness`), and your input XML. Also, it is not clear to me what you are asking. Perhaps that's easier to explain with a full XML input, a full stylesheet and the full output you expect.

Comment: "*Is it possible...*" Anything is possible, but not everything is easy. XSLT's strength is in manipulating XML nodes, not comma (or semicolon) separated values. Which version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: BTW, I am quite sure that `translate($string,'&amp;amp;','&amp;')` does **not** do what you think it does. You should try it with a string like: `"Map&amp;Spam"`.